# Google Places API Web Service shows photo_reference, but Javascript library doesn't

Tags: google-places-api

I'm building a basic places search page and I'm using the Google Places Javascript library for it ([text search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#TextSearchRequests)). I do get one "photo" element back, but I noticed that the "photo_reference" field is empty. Here a sample request:

```
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map);
service.textSearch({query: 'harbour bridge'}, this.callback.bind(this));
```

Repsonse:

```
{
   "formatted_address":"Sydney Harbour Bridge, Sydney NSW, Australia",
   "geometry":{
      "location":{
         "lat":-33.8523063,
         "lng":151.21078710000006
      }
   },
   "icon":"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
   "id":"e22913360d0b946d099c7a32a77a95e49f9ead66",
   "name":"Sydney Harbour Bridge",
   "photos":[{
     "height":4000,
     "html_attributions":["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/113178678511744469415/photos\">Jasper Straver</a>"],
     "width":6000
   }],
   "place_id":"ChIJ49XqJV2uEmsRPsTAF7eOlGg",
   "rating":4.7,
   "reference":"[...]",
   "types":["point_of_interest", "establishment"],
   "html_attributions":[]
}
```

If I do the same request using the web service, I get the photo_reference. Example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?key=[...]&query=harbour%20bridge
```

Response:

```
{
     "formatted_address" : "Sydney Harbour Bridge, Sydney NSW, Australia",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : -33.8523063,
           "lng" : 151.2107871
        }
     },
     "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
     "id" : "e22913360d0b946d099c7a32a77a95e49f9ead66",
     "name" : "Sydney Harbour Bridge",
     "photos" : [
        {
           "height" : 4000,
           "html_attributions" : ["\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/113178678511744469415/photos\"\u003eJasper Straver\u003c/a\u003e"],
           "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAAY-WUame_CRFnMFmUN4UlvFHI7o3tQOqXJxTkjQINgzMQOOheBzLPIm43dlIAIkhFyugFAw8fnf-ItEiUp1j48B23sCDFRtCWM123euhDif_P1jYkvFAjDrPxq1rCnmi2EhCt6LpVl5W-AKPLRkW_tzs6GhRlG4dx2CVuTNZZMFFo3eYMSFWzGg",
           "width" : 6000
        }
     ],
     "place_id" : "ChIJ49XqJV2uEmsRPsTAF7eOlGg",
     "rating" : 4.7,
     "reference" : "[...]",
     "types" : [ "point_of_interest", "establishment" ]
  }
```

How come there is a difference between the JS and Web Services API? How can I get the photo_reference from the JS library? (I don't want to make a getDetails(...) request for each search result)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`photo_reference` is for the Google Places API **Web Service**.  With the Places Javascript library you can just call [`getUrl`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlacePhoto) on the elements of the `photos` array, e.g. `place.photos[0].getUrl({maxWidth: 1000})`.

Like the Web Service, search results won't have more than 1 photo.

Comment: I was calling getUrl() without maxWidth param and it wasn't working.  Thank you.  Google needs to update the docs.